# Importing React Component from bundled file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a bunch of React components in a folder and I can import each one individually like this:

```
import Component1 from '../components/component1/component1';
import Component2 from '../components/component2/component2';
```

Using the components like this works fine. However, when I bundle all the components using Webpack, the following code returns an empty object when I try to import the component.

```
import Component1 from '../dist/bundle.js';
```

I can't render this component. How do I export the components when bundling files?

Comment: My understanding is that Webpack is generating a `bundle.js` file for use by browsers, not other libraries.

Comment: can you post your webpack config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put you cannot import any modules from a bundle.
You need to include this code inside the source and then bundle it together

Comment: So do I have to use another tool like Grunt/Gulp to build my component library. And then include that in the source code?

Comment: grunt/gulp are just task runners. bundlers are browserify and webpack and u cant access anything inside of a bundle

Comment: is there any way to share the react native components as bundle file and import that component from the bundle file @Sagi_Avinash_Varma

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that. In my situation I needed react components in backbone application so what I did:

In react exposed components that should be importable by exporting them in entry point (usually `index.js`) like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';

export {
    React,
    ReactDOM,
    Header
};
```

Made my bundle output as library:

```
   output: {
        path: /some/path/of/your/lib,
        library: 'reactapp',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        filename: `app${jsExtension}`,
    },
```

Then bind name to file path in requirejs config:

```
reactapp: '/some/path/of/your/lib/app.js'
```

Then in code I can import that bundle as `reactapp` like:

```
define(["reactapp"], function(reactapp) {
    // reactapp is object containing React, ReactDOM, Header
});
```